# Java Spring Boot versão do projeto

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

Preciso de pegar o valor da versão em meu projeto spring boot para criar um serviço que retorna esse valor , o valor em questão seria version no build.gradle.

```
group = 'br.com.xxxxx'
version = '0.0.2'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
```

ja tentei diversas formas como por exemplo:

`ProjectInfoProperties.Build.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()`

segue abaixo minha gradle:

```
buildscript {

ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.3.RELEASE"
}
```

mas isso só me traz a versão do spring boot. 
Quem puder me ajudar, agradeço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é possível. O Spring tem um bean chamado [`BuildProperties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/info/BuildProperties.html), que possui algumas informações do projeto, como o número de versão.

Para isso, você precisa do seguinte:

1) 
a) Se o projeto for Maven, adicionar o seguinte ao `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>build-info</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-info</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

b) Se o projeto for Gradle, adicionar o seguinte ao `build.gradle`:

```
springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}
```

Ao buildar o projeto, o Spring vai gerar no caminho `\build\resources\main\META-INF` o arquivo `build-info.properties` e disponibilizar para injeção o *bean* `BuildProperties`, que, entre outros métodos, possui o método [`getVersion()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/info/BuildProperties.html#getVersion--), que retorna a versão.

Relativamente a código é isso, porém, caso você execute o projeto pela IDE (o que é o mais provável), você pode receber um erro de bean não encontrado. Para resolver isso, caso sua IDE seja a Intellij, vá em `Edit > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle (ou Maven, depende do seu projeto) > Runner` e clique a opção *Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle (ou maven)*. Isso porque a task do Gradle/Maven que gera o arquivo `build-info.properties` é a `bootBuildInfo`, que não é a task padrão que a Intellij utiliza, daí o erro.

Ao executar `System.out.println(build.getVersion());` num projeto de teste seguindo os passos que descrevi, recebi como output a versão que se encontra informada no `build.gradle` do projeto:

```
//0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Um artigo útil pode ser encontrado [aqui](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/spring-boot-version/).

Comment: fiz da maneira que falou mas me retornou o seguinte erro: Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'springBoot()'!

Comment: consegui agora mudando buildInfo de lugar em meu arquivo gradle. muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa interessante para esta situação é a seguinte:

Adicionar no `build.gradle`:

```
springBoot {    
    buildInfo() 
}
```

No source, para pegar as informações:

```
@Autowired
private BuildProperties buildProperties;
```

Por exemplo, para pegar a versão:

```
String version = buildProperties.getVersion();
```